# Issue with FFMPEG drawtext

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i /home/mysite/public_html/videos/thankyou/thankyou_1.mp4 -strict -2 -vf 
"[in]drawtext=fontfile=/home/mysite/fonts/OswaldFont/Oswald-Bold.ttf: x=450: 
y=150: fontsize=152: fontcolor=0xAE0216@1: draw='if(gt(n,40),lt(n,300))':
text='THANK YOU',drawtext=fontfile=/home/mysite/fonts/OswaldFont/Oswald-Bold.ttf: 
x=450: y=320: fontsize=200: fontcolor=0xAE0216@1: draw='if(gt(n,50),lt(n,300))':
text='JAMISON'" /home/mysite/public_html/videos/thankyou_2.mp4
```

When running the above, I'm getting the following. It seems to run properly on other distributions. Not sure where to check next.

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x2835480] Option 'draw' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x283f980] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=/home/mysite/fonts/OswaldFont/Oswald-Bold.ttf: x=450: y=150: fontsize=152: fontcolor=0xAE0216@1: draw=if(gt(n,40),lt(n,300)): text=THANK YOU'

Error opening filters!
```

Additionally, this original command works fine in Ubuntu, but give the seen error when running in centOS.

Answer (score 1):

According the the FFmpeg `drawtext` filter documentation:

> **draw**
>
> This option does not exist, please see the timeline system

This means you should use [timeline editing](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) instead.

To do that replace the `draw='...'` part of your command with:

`enable=if(gt(n\,50)\,lt(n\,300))`

You should also check:

- FFmpeg versions on each machine. You might have an older version installed on Ubuntu, which supports the `draw` option, and a newer version on CentOS in which the option was removed.
- if the font files exist